# Why skiplist memory locality is poor but balanced tree is good?

Tags: caching, memory, redis

A guy once challenged antirez(author of Redis) why Redis use skip list for the implementation sorted sets in [ycombinator](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1171423):

> I was looking at Redis yesterday and noticed this. Is there any
>   particular reason you chose skip list instead of btrees except for
>   simplicity? Skip lists consume more memory in pointers and are
>   generally slower than btrees because of **poor memory locality** so
>   traversing them means lots of cache misses. I also suggested a way to
>   improve throughput when you guarantee each command's durability (at
>   the end of the wiki page):
>   http://code.google.com/p/redis/wiki/AppendOnlyFileHowto Also, have you
>   thought about accommodating read-only traffic in an additional thread
>   as a way to utilize at least two cores efficiently while sharing the
>   same memory?

Then antirez answered:

> There are a few reasons: 1) They are not very memory intensive. It's
>   up to you basically. Changing parameters about the probability of a
>   node to have a given number of levels will make then less memory
>   intensive than btrees. 2) A sorted set is often target of many ZRANGE
>   or ZREVRANGE operations, that is, traversing the skip list as a linked
>   list. With this operation the cache locality of skip lists is at least
>   as good as with other kind of balanced trees. 3) They are simpler to
>   implement, debug, and so forth. For instance thanks to the skip list
>   simplicity I received a patch (already in Redis master) with augmented
>   skip lists implementing ZRANK in O(log(N)). It required little changes
>   to the code. About the Append Only durability & speed, I don't think
>   it is a good idea to optimize Redis at cost of more code and more
>   complexity for a use case that IMHO should be rare for the Redis
>   target (fsync() at every command). Almost no one is using this feature
>   even with ACID SQL databases, as the performance hint is big anyway.
>   About threads: our experience shows that Redis is mostly I/O bound.
>   I'm using threads to serve things from Virtual Memory. The long term
>   solution to exploit all the cores, assuming your link is so fast that
>   you can saturate a single core, is running multiple instances of Redis
>   (no locks, almost fully scalable linearly with number of cores), and
>   using the "Redis Cluster" solution that I plan to develop in the
>   future.

I read that carefully, but I can't understand why skip list comes with poor memory locality? And why balanced tree will lead a good memory locality?

---

In my opinion, memory locality is about storing data in a continuous memory. I think it's true when read data in address `x`, CPU will load the data in address `x+1` into cache(Based on some experiments by C, years ago). So traversal an array will result a high possibility cache hit and we can say array has good memory locality.

But when comes to skip list and balanced tree, both aren't arrays and don't store data continuously. So I think their memory locality are both poor. So could anyone explain a little for me?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the guy meant that there is only one key value at skip list **node** (in case of default implementation) and `N` keys at b-tree **node** with linear layout. So we can load a bunch of b-tree keys from **node** into the cache.

you've said:

> both aren't arrays and don't store data continuously

but we do. We store data continiously at b-tree **node**.

Comment: So you create a large array storing the whole b-tree? And how to handle when b-tree grows? Create a new array with double size, like HashMap of Java?

Comment: No I don't. I create an array for each non-leaf  node.